# Почему "господа", но "дамы"?

Tags: этикет

Сейчас обращением "господин" никого не удивишь. Соответственно, к женщине обращаются "госпожа". Но при этом, когда выступающий говорит с большой аудиторией, он употребляет обращение "дамы и господа". Почему так? Если "дамы", то тогда логично обращаться "кавалеры". Или уже тогда "господа" и "госпожи".
Я предполагаю, что причина в несколько неуклюжем звучании слова "госпожи", но, с другой стороны, неуклюжим оно нам кажется именно потому, что его заменили на "дам".

Answer (score 3):

Ну да, путаница тут имеет место. Об этом кто только не писал.
Я помню это у Солоухина, году эдак в 65-м...)))

К сожалению, ничего кроме как выражать недоумение не остается. 
Но причины вы, хоть и приблизительно угадали, изложили не точно.
Фокус в том, что "госпожи" в этом значении не пойдет, т.к. имеет весьма специфическое употребление, а "господа" уже само по себе включает и господ женского полу - и в этом его отличие от западноевропейских аналогов. Оставить же просто "господа", что было бы вполне логично с точки зрения истории и значения слова, будет восприниматься как сексизм, да еще на фоне советского "товарищи", самими товарищами начисто лишенного половых признаков. Наконец, "дамы и кавалеры", безупречное с гендерных позиций, совершенно не из той "оперы".

Ничего не остается как мириться с "дамами и господами". И радуйтесь, пока нам снова "товарищей и товарок" не спустили указующим перстом.

Answer (score 0):

"Дамы и господа", так же как "леди и джентельмены" - это результат революционного перелома в обществе, произошедшего сначала в Европе, а затем и в России, при котором с женщинакми стали считаться, уважать, допустили к управлению политическими процессами государств. До этого **госпожа** была всего лишь **хозяйкой** дома, при том что господин был не просто хозяином, но  **властелином**.